# Go back to my home page

Tags: urls

how can I target home page when clicking go-back after placing order , I used redirection plugin but it permanently redirect . I am only looking to redirect to home page when order is placed and I am on checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use woocommerce_thankyou action to achieve above

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_goBack');
  
function custom_goBack( $order_id )
{
echo '<a href="'.get_home_url().'">Go Back</a>';
}
```

Comment: no i am looking for goback history button of browser , on clicking that button i want to go to home page.

Comment: you want to be redirected to previous page right?
you can use wp_get_referer()  function instead of get_home_url()

Comment: i want to go to home page url , when someone click goback-history  button of browser after checkout .